# ExtendedItemHandle null after calling newExtendendItem

Tags: java, birt, rcp

I have to refactor and migrate legacy code from pre 2010. Documentation is bad and I am pretty new to RCP and BIRT coding as well.

The thing is, that we replaced the broken ant build process with a maven tycho process and we got a running application. Now i need to fix a report which somehow does not get displayed and we dont know why.

```
    ExtendedItemHandle eih = elementFactory.newExtendedItem( null, "Chart" );
```

The newExtendedItem method returns null for some unknown reason and I cant figure out why. Since the code is so old i figured it may have something to do with the target platform, but I dont know where to look. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I should probably give some context:

```
// A session handle for all open reports
    SessionHandle session = new DesignEngine( null ).newSessionHandle( (ULocale) null );

    // Create a new report
    reportDesignHandle = session.createDesign( );

    // Element factory is used to create instances of BIRT elements.
    elementFactory = reportDesignHandle.getElementFactory( );
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a missing plugin. I dont know, which one, but eventually adding the whole target platform to my running configuration fixed it.